# Java ArrayList of positions alternates after updating

Tags: java, arraylist, timer, keylistener, repaint

First of all, sorry!
I tried debugging everything myself but I just couldn't figure out the problem. So in broad terms I created a green grid and a red player inside the grid. I keep an ArrayList of all the Cells and what color they should be. I update the position of my player with KeyListeners. When I run the program the player wasn't moving. I will link all my code below so you guys can follow along. This was my debugging process. Please keep in mind I am an inexperienced programmer

- First I system outed everything and looked at what ran. Everything ran.
- So I finally made the observation that the Array List does keep track of my player and key listeners work because I only got after pressing w (moves up) a few times I would get an out of bounds error. However, on screen it didn't move
- Next I looked at if it had to do something with repaint because the player wasn't moving but the ArrayList was updating. However I added a new square and saw that when I have x++ it would move.
- Next, I tried seeing if it was something with my thread (timer). I changed the timing from 7 ms to 1000 ms. In the console I had the playerX position be printed to console. This is when I saw that it was printing in pairs. I start position x at 5. The pairs go as following 5 5 5 6 5 7 5 8 5 9 5 10 5.
- I changed the starting position of player x to 10 and got 10 10 10 10 10 11 10 12 10 13. So this makes me believe that the grid is being called multiple times in my program. However, I couldn't find anything.

I honestly think this could be a hardware issue as well. This laptop is really slow. Anyways, if anyone can help much appreciated. 
FYI code underneath has multiple classes, seemed easiest. Pretty sure error must be in the Game Panel Class. If I can clarify or give any information please just ask. So why does PlayerX alternate?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry pal, but chances are not so good that somebody will want to spend the time required to digest all this code.

Comment: Yea I understand I am just really confused and have no where else to go. I have asked friends and our "Comp Sci" teacher but no one knows how to help me. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: You should add code snippet, the part where you're facing problem.

Comment: Also your `GridSystem` class is incomplete. Can't reproduce it sadly.

Comment: So sorry about that I believe I fixed the GridSystem Class

Comment: Added an answer. Next time make sure you debug this yourself, you could have noticed that the `updatePlayer` method is getting called twice and only one of those 2 updates the values so probably there are two instances of it out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through your code I found the culprit: You are creating 2 `GamePanel` objects in the constructor of your `Main` class.

It should look like this:

```
public Main()
{
    frame.setSize(SIZE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    GamePanel panel = new GamePanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setFocusable(true);
    frame.addKeyListener(panel);
}
```

And with that it moves. It still is full of bugs and doesn't look nice... but it moves so you can do further work on it.

Also:

1. The `super.addKeyListener()` in your `GamePanel` does nothing.
2. Don't override `paint` but `paintComponent`.
3. Don't cast your `Graphics` to `Graphics2D` if there is no need for it.
4. Definitely improve on your formatting and think about adding some documentation.
5. Don't add a `KeyListener` to a parent object and let a child object consume the events. That's a weird design.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, I really appreciate it.